# Excel Conditional Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to set some conditional formatting in excel. Specifically, 2 statements in one conditional rule.

I am capturing a field called 'expiry date'. When the date is exceeded I want to change the color as well as the text within the cell.

I have achieved 50% of this already with the below statement. The below statement is calculating when the date is exceeded based off of Today's date - then Excel is changing the color of the cell to RED.

```
 =IF($G$8="","",$G$8<=TODAY())
```

However, how do I get the text in the cell to then change from e.g. "in date" to "expired". I am currently selecting the text "in date" and "expired" from a data validation list.

Comment: You can't have a cell formula reference itself so would need VBA if I understand correctly.

Comment: You have two options here:

1) In each cell use this formula: `=IF($G$8<=TODAY(),"In Date","Expired")`

2) In the conditional formatting settings for the cells you want to affect open "format" go to "format cells" go to "custom" and type in "Expired". This will change how the cell is displayed but will not change the value stored in the cell.